# How to fix module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm using InceptionV4 from [here](https://github.com/systemcorp-ai/InceptionV4/blob/master/inceptionv4.py)

but i got this error message

My tensorflow and keras is 2.5.0

```
AttributeError
module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'
  File "C:\Labbb\inception\InceptionV4-master\inceptionv4.py", line 219, in create_inception_v4
    init = Input((299,299, 8))
  File "C:\Labbb\inception\InceptionV4-master\inceptionv4.py", line 259, in <module>
    model = create_inception_v4(load_weights=check)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'
```

```
def create_inception_v4(nb_classes=int(args["num_classes"]), load_weights=check):
model = create_inception_v4(load_weights=check)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=float(args['learning_rate']), decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True), metrics=["accuracy"])
hist = model.fit_generator(train_datagen,steps_per_epoch=int(args['50']),epochs=int(args['3']),verbose=True,validation_data=val_datagen,validation_steps=10,callbacks=[mc, tensorboard])
```

I tried use this line "from tensorflow.keras." instead of "from keras.", but not work

```
from keras.layers import Input, merge, Dropout, Dense, Flatten, Activation
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D, Convolution2D, AveragePooling2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
from keras.utils.training_utils import multi_gpu_model
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
from tensorflow.keras.layers import concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55496289/how-to-fix-attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-get-default-gr
This can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
```

Comment: In my code, I already add this line

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problems with '`from tensorflow.python.keras import backend`'

Comment: not work, so sad